# What's the effect of the red pools in the Paths of the Drowned

Tags: diablo-iii

When you walk through one of the red pools (Blood Springs), your avatar takes on a red tint, and an animation appears above its head.  Similar happens to your followers if they go through a red pool.

What's the effect of it?  Does it affect your health (it doesn't appear to unless I have some mitigating effect of a piece of equipment), or is it another "zero effect but looks cool" thing like the tar pits in act 2, which the Enchantress endearingly tells you not to walk through because your boots will get dirty?

Comment: You probably mitigate it, I've seen people die to them (sure, they were ~lvl 50 in a T4 lvl 70 rift with barely any equipment[because powerleveling was going on])

Comment: I believe they do poison damage, so if you're wearing a [Mara's Kaleidascope](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/maras-kaleidoscope) (which grants immunity to poison damage) you're not noticing it.

Comment: Pools do damage. I am not sure about the element or strength, hence I am not answering, but if you lack toughness and recovery for your difficulty (like when leveling), the damage is very noticeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in

the Blood Springs deal Poison damage, which tallies with what PawnInGameOfLife commented.

Mara's Kaleidoscope is shown in that video as actually turning them into "healing spots".

Answer (score 2):

The pools of blood found in this and adjacent areas actually apply a DOT effect on your character.

If you have a large amount of health or health regen, the effect will probably be unnoticeable.

When you walk through one of those pools, open your Character Inventory page, and press Square (PS3/4) or X (360/xbone) to see the details page and you should see a description of the effect.

Comment: A "DOT" effect?

Comment: **DOT** in rpg-lingo means **D**amage-**O**ver-**T**ime. You also got **HOT** which means **H**ealing-**O**ver-**T**ime but isn't that much used with Diablo.

Answer (score -3):

It sounds like you might be referring to Arcane power. It's caused from an attack type arcane, and deals arcane damage to you. Here's an image I found. If this is what you are refering to.

[image]

Comment: Pretty sure the question is about those red pools outside in the swamp.

Comment: @Arperum Yes, the ones that come and go.